# Reject IP that is already in white list

Tags: firewalld

Time ago I set

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-source=170.8.0.0/18
```

Today I ran

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='170.8.1.1' reject";
```

1. Which of both prevails?
2. What if the order is reversed? First reject an IP and then add it to a whitelisted range.

Comment: what is preventing you from performing a test?

Comment: It’s just an example of a generic question

Answer (score 1):

The command which is executed later will override policy. Later command will override previous command.